# My python code doesn't recognize the update of data in aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, telegram-bot

I wrote my python code at Jupyter notebook and let it run by aws server.
However, it does not recognize the update of the data in s3, which contains telegram bot user info.
For example, user 1 chat with the bot based on DB1.
After that, user 2 started to chat with the bot, but Jupyter notebook cannot update user 1 info to DB1 in s3.
If I run jupyter notebook code by aws ec2, how can i update/manage the data base?

```
def start(update, context):
    print("start\n")
    chat_id=update.effective_chat.id
    print(type(chat_id))
    pdb.set_trace()
    print(user_info_dic)
    if (user_info_dic[str(chat_id)]!=None):#chat_id가 이미 존재함.
        print("chat_id 존재\n")
        key = user_info_dic[str(chat_id)]['key']
        email = user_info_dic[str(chat_id)]['email']
        update.message.reply_text(
            "이미 방문하신 적이 있으세요."
            f"키워드:{key}, 이메일 주소 : {email} "
            "수정하고 싶으시다면 /yes를, 그렇지 않다면 /no를 입력하세요."
        )
        before=1
    else:
        print("처음\n")
        update.message.reply_text(
            "안녕하세요 :-) \n"
            "당신의 편안한 정보 습득을 위해 몇 가지 정보를 얻고자 합니다. \n"
            "동의하시면 /yes를, 그렇지 않다면 /no를 적어주세요."
        )
    return AGREE


def yes(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(
        "동의해주셔서 감사합니다.\n"
        "당신이 검색하고픈 키워드는 무엇입니까? \n"
        "Ex)바이오, 뷰티, 여행 "
    )
    return KEYWORD

def no(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(
        "다음에 기회가 된다면 찾아오시길 바랍니다."
    )
    return ConversationHandler.END

def key(update, context):
    k=update.message.text
    chat_id=update.effective_chat.id

    file=str(chat_id)+".json" #ex) 709732.json 리스트 형태로 파일 저장
    if (before==0): #처음 입력한 사람
        user_info_dic[str(chat_id)]['key']=k #{'chat_id': [key, email, file_path],...} => file_path: log of his update posts
        user_info_dic[str(chat_id)]['path']=file

        empty=json.dumps([])
        client.put_object(Bucket="aws-crawling-data", Body=empty, Key=file)

    else:#전에 한 번 입력했던 사람
        user_info_dic[str(chat_id)]['key']=k #[k, email, path]

    update.message.reply_text(
        f"당신이 입력한 키워드가 {k}가 맞나요?\n"
        "맞다면 이메일 주소를 입력해주세요 (ex: hongkildong@naver.com 등등). 잘못 입력하셨다면 /retry1을 입력해주십시오."
    )
    return PASS1

def retry1(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(
        "키워드를 다시 입력해주세요.\n"
     )
    return KEYWORD

def email(update, context):
    e=update.message.text #남성, 여성, 기타
    chat_id=update.effective_chat.id
    user_info_dic[str(chat_id)]['email']=e #(k, e, path)

    update.message.reply_text(
        f"당신이 입력한 이메일이 {e} 맞나요?\n"
        "맞다면 /end를 입력해주세요. 잘못 입력하셨다면 /retry2를 입력해주십시오."
    )

    return PASS2

def retry2(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(
        "이메일 주소를 다시 입력해주세요."
     )
    return EMAIL

def end(update, context):
    update_user_info=json.dumps(user_info_dic)
    client.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET1, Body=update_user_info, Key=KEY)

    update.message.reply_text(
        "수고하셨습니다. 저에게 주신 이메일로 공지를 전달해드리도록 하겠습니다."
    )
    return ConversationHandler.END

def error(update, context):
    logger.warning("update '%s' caused error '%s'", update, context.error)

def main():
    to=s3.Object(BUCKET1,"Test_test_dest_bot_token.txt") #이후에 bpp_info_token으로 변경
    token=to.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').rstrip() #string form

    updater=Updater(token=token, use_context=True)
    dp=updater.dispatcher
    conv_handler=ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],

        states={  #키워드 -> 이메일
            AGREE:[CommandHandler('yes', yes),
                    CommandHandler('no', no)],
            KEYWORD:[MessageHandler(Filters.text, key)],
            PASS1:[CommandHandler('retry1', retry1),
                   MessageHandler(Filters.text, email)],
            EMAIL:[MessageHandler(Filters.text, email)],
            PASS2:[CommandHandler('retry2', retry2),
                   CommandHandler('end', end)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('end', end)]
    )

    dp.add_handler(conv_handler)
    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)
    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()
    #print("before \n")

    updater.idle()
    #print("before \n")

if __name__=='__main__':
    s3=boto3.resource('s3')
    user=s3.Object(bucket_name=BUCKET1,key=KEY)
    user_body=user.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8') #string form
    user_info_dic=json.loads(user_body) #string form -> dictionary (json) form # chat_id: {'email':, 'key':, 'path":txt file}
    print(user_info_dic)
    #user.delete()    #delete 없어도 덮어쓰기 가능

    client=boto3.client('s3')
    main()
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use dynamodb for storing user info?

Comment: That is a lot of code for us to read. Could you possibly provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?